# Individual domain cache invalidation AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, multiple-domains, invalidation

I have CloudFront distribution with multiple domains. As example all domains like *.mydomain.com caching in my distribution. And now I have problem with invalidation. I can't set invalidation path like this one.mydomain.com or http://one.mydomain.com. Every times when I need invalidate cache I must invalidate cache for everyone domais which I have. With the path /*

But my site provide page editor, and I want invalidate page after each save in editor. How can I invalidate cache for individual domain?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is currently not possible to invalidate by domain and Cloudfront invalidation by path only.

If you plan to automate the invalidation once a page is saved, you can use the AWS SDK for CloudFront and call the [createInvalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#createInvalidation-property) method from your code.

Comment: Hi Ashan. Tnx for response. I tried use sdk, but when set url to path list I got error about invalid invalidation path.